# Finding the sum of the max of a column

Tags: sql

I have the following piece of code:

```
select  sum(max(p.highest_market_value_in_eur)) as value, c.name  from Transfermarket.dbo.players$ p
left join Transfermarket.dbo.player_valuations v
on p.player_id = v.player_id
inner join Transfermarket.dbo.competitions$ c
on c.competition_id = v.player_club_domestic_competition_id
where c.name = 'Ligue 1' and last_season = 2022
group by   c.name;
```

Apparently, performing aggregate functions on expressions containing an aggregate doesn't work. Is there any other way? I suppose I could use a subquery, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: need a bit more info here. what do you mean by max of the sum? if you're calculating a sum, that would be every value added together, no? so you would have 1 value and you cant find the max of 1 value.

Comment: Let's say I have a player that has multiple rows with value. I want to find the max value of these players, and then find the sum for all of them. For example, Messi has highest_market_value_in_eur values of 1000,2000,3000. Neymar has values of 1,2,3,4. I want to find max value of Messi (3000), max of Neymar (4) and find the sum of them.

Comment: update your question with sample table

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're going to want to do this in two steps.

If i am understanding your question correctly, you are wanting to find the maximum `p.highest_market_value_in_eur` for each player in the players table for a given `c.name` where the `last_season` is 2022. Then you want sum for all players in that competition.

Lets find our max first:

```
select
    max(p.highest_market_value_in_eur) as value,
    p.player_id as player_id
from
    Transfermarket.dbo.players$ p
left join Transfermarket.dbo.player_valuations v on p.player_id = v.player_id
inner join Transfermarket.dbo.competitions$ c on c.competition_id = v.player_club_domestic_competition_id
where c.name = 'Ligue 1' and last_season = 2022
group by p.player_id;
```

The above query will find the max value of `p.highest_market_value_in_eur` for each player where the competition name is 'Ligue 1' and the last season is 2022. Notice that the first step here is grouping on a different value. This is because we want the max PER PLAYER - so we ask for the max and group by player.

Now that we've found the max for every player in Ligue 1 from 2022, lets calculate our sum to find 'Total Market Value in EUR for all players competing in Ligue 1 from 2022'. We'll do this by calling the `sum()` aggregate function on the results from our first query. we'll do this in the form of a subquery:

```
select
    sum(value)
from
    (select
        max(p.highest_market_value_in_eur) as value,
        p.player_id as player_id
    from
        Transfermarket.dbo.players$ p
    left join Transfermarket.dbo.player_valuations v on p.player_id = v.player_id
    inner join Transfermarket.dbo.competitions$ c on c.competition_id = v.player_club_domestic_competition_id
    where c.name = 'Ligue 1' and last_season = 2022
    group by p.player_id) max_per_player;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I was looking for. I knew it was something like that, but I couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @GBilianis if you feel this answer was adequate please accept as correct so others may rely it's validity